# System.setOut() to a Preferences node

Tags: java, io, outputstream, system.out

How can I achieve the following, where `prefsOutputStream` is the pseudo-variable I'm aiming to make:

```java
PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

System.setOut(prefsOutputStream);

System.out.println("Foo Bar");

String logString = Preferences.userRoot().node("app").get("stdout","");
oldOut.println(logString); // Outputs "Foo Bar" into the console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I thought of is:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        super.flush();
        String old = Preferences.userRoot().node("app").get("stdout", "");
        Preferences.userRoot().node("app").put("stdout", old + toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        count = 0;
    }
}, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This creates a `PrintStream` that outputs to a byte array output stream. The `PrintStream` will be automatically flushed whenever you print a newline character (e.g. by using `println`). This will cause the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to flush, which will write everything written to the stream since the last flush, to the preferences.

Comment: thank you. It worked perfectly